# Php Parse error: syntax error: unexpected ','

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm kinda new to php, i was doing function and this syntax error happened:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b71p7.png)

```
function invalidUid($username) {
$result;
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"), $username) { #that is line 15
    $result = true;
}
else {
    $result = false;
}
return $result;
```

}

Comment: What's the `, $username` supposed to do in your `if`?

Comment: Think the first close bracket should be after `$username`.

Comment: @NigelRen still gives error

Comment: @j08691 function checks if there is numbers or letters in this $username